# ConstraintLayout in RecyclerView Selector

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-selector, android-constraintlayout

I am using a ConstraintLayout as a Root in an adapter item (using RecyclerView). My issue is that I am not able to make the selector work on pre-lollipop devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/material_cell_height"
android:foreground="@drawable/selector_cell"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/material_content_padding"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/material_content_padding"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Cell.Body2"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_toolbar"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview_author"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_overflow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute,NewApi,RtlSymmetry,PrivateResource"
    tools:text="The Best Product" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_author"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/material_content_padding"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/material_content_padding"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Cell.Body"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_title"
    tools:text="John Doe and Band" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_cover"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_overflow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textview_title"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24px" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my selector for pre-lollipop devices:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_window_focused="false" />
<item android:drawable="@color/cell_touch_effect" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/cell_touch_effect" android:state_activated="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/cell_touch_effect" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add into your `ConstraintLayout` those tags:

`android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"`